# Use of return in deferred computation in Ocaml Async

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

I know that this question may look very silly but whenever I search to get a relevant answer, I only get general questions about return values, so...

I'm studying deferred computation through OCaml, and I get the very basic concept of it. But when I was reading through functions regarding deferred computation (mainly, ASync docs from from Janestreet; https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/async_kernel/#Deferred.t), I saw return function, and I don't get what it's for.

let x = return 1

produces a deferred value that is determined immediately, but what is the point of assigning immediate values if using deferred computation already? Why not just assign a normal value to it directly? Is it because other functions (like bind function) only takes deferred value or are there other good reasons?

Examples are greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: `return`, `bind` and `join` are verbs belonging to the [tag:monad] terminology. Monads are simply structured sets with very interesting properties. The `return` function lifts ordinary values to such structure, which may then be manipulated following those properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may think of `return` as a function that creates deferred values. And it is really plays its role, when you define it in a context of other deferred value. Let's go to the example. Suppose we have a function that reads a char form input channel, and uppercases it.

```
let read_uppercased chan = 
  Reader.read_char >>= function
  | `Eof -> return `Eof
  | `Ok ch -> let ch = Char.uppercase ch in
              return (`Ok ch)
```

In this function we actually have two uses of a `return` function. The former indeed creates a deferred value from a constant, indeed we do not need to «wait» before eof occurs to create this value. For example we can create a constant deferred

```
let return_eof = return `Eof
```

and use it anywhere.

The second occurrence is much more interesting. It creates a deferred from a value that will be determined only somewhere in the future (or maybe it won't be ever determined). But the cool idea is that we do not need to actualy wait for the value to be determined in order to define a computation on it. So, in order to bring a value from future, we use `bind` function, then we do some computation, but afterwards we need to fix the flow of time, and to `return` a result back to the future... Well, if all this don't make sense to you, just erase it from your mind. Different people likes different metaphors.

Indeed, maybe it would be more clarifying for you to know, that underneath the hood this return just connects a callback function to the chain of of other callbacks.